# Get result from two table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get result from two tables in one query, but the problem is I need columns from both the tables in my where clause-
Example

```
SELECT activity.*,
    (
      SELECT photos 
      FROM posts 
      WHERE activity.content_id = posts.record_number
    ) as p 
FROM activity 
WHERE activity.liked_post > 0 OR activity.comments > 0 OR p > 0 
ORDER BY date DESC 
LIMIT 0,10
```

This example does not work. I have no idea how to make this query work. If `p = 0` the record should be skipped but `content_id` can be 0 or any number, if `content_id > 0` then need to check photos in posts table, if `content_id = 0` we must skip.

So `photos` in `posts` table have value 0 or 1.

`content_id` in `activity` table is just same ID/record_number from posts

Maybe a little confusing question but don't know how to explain

Comment: Pls provide sample data with expected results. It is a bit diffcult to follow your description only. Btw, this sounds like a simple left join.

Comment: so you only want records where content_id > 0 `AND` activity.comments > 0 `AND` p > 0?

Comment: Data is always number.
Just need to skip content_id from activity table if photos = 0 in posts table.

Comment: @isaace should  be ``OR``

Comment: and what about comments `activity.comments > 0` ? sounds like a regular `JOIN`

Comment: `Just need to skip content_id from activity table if photos = 0` sounds like an `AND`

Comment: ``activity.comments`` can be also 0 or bigger, i can check it with ``activity.comments > 0`` it's a number ID from comments table

Comment: if activity.comments is not > 0 then you want to skip it?

Comment: Sure but will check ``activity.content_id`` OR ``activity.liked_post`` because i have add ``OR``

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a sub-select for the photo, use a join. The p > 0 in your query is taken care of by using a join. Only rows that have photos will be included in the results.

This should return the rows you expect:

```
SELECT a.*,
    p.photos
FROM activity a
LEFT JOIN posts p
    ON a.content_id = p.record_number
WHERE (a.liked_post > 0 OR a.comments > 0)
    AND (a.content_id = p.record_number AND content_id > 0)
        OR liked_post > 0)
ORDER BY date DESC 
LIMIT 0,10;
```

**Note:** I aliased the table names to reduce the amount of typing needed.

Comment: it could have a join and photos field can still be zero. I think you should add the check.

Comment: The OPs select doesn't check for photos > 0, he checks for p > 0 (won't work since p is a table alias).

Comment: No its not what i need, sometimes ``liked_post`` can be bigger that 0 in this case we don't need check photos and i should be get this result.
We need to check photos only if ``content_id `` is bigger than 0

Comment: Only what i get with this query is ``liked_post ``

Comment: @Sloan Thrasher maybe you are not understand me well but we need to check ``photos`` only if ``content_id`` is > 0

Comment: @mKagac ... I think the gist of what @SloanThrasher was getting across was that you needed a `JOIN` statement instead of nested `SELECT`s.  There was no need to answer your own question, as the "theory" behind this answer, corrected your issue.  You could ask @Sloan to edit this answer to reflect what actually worked, and give credit where credit is due.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution

```
SELECT a.*,
       p.photos
FROM activity a
LEFT JOIN content p ON a.content_id = p.record_number
WHERE (a.friend_with > 0
       OR a.liked_post > 0
       OR a.comments > 0)
  OR (a.content_id = p.record_number
      AND photos > 0)
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```